# Snapkit and Xcode Injection

Tags: ios, xcode, user-interface, uikit

I'm using Injection Live Rendering and Snapkit. Every time I'm saving project, and changing constraints, so project can live render, Xcode console showing me I should make a symbolic brakepoint (UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints). But when I'm building project not using live rendering (just pressing build button) it is displaying properly.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

let leftView = UIView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.addSubview(leftView)
    makeLeftView()
}

func makeLeftView() {
    leftView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.left.equalTo(view.snp.left).offset(10)
        make.top.equalTo(view.snp.top).offset(10)
    }
    leftView.frame.size = CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)
    leftView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
}

@objc func injected() {
    makeLeftView()
}
}
```

What can cause this problem? Constraints are reloading in some strange way?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to set width and height in makeConstraints closure instead set frame size of your leftView

```
leftView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
  make.left.equalTo(view.snp.left).offset(10)
  make.top.equalTo(view.snp.top).offset(10)
  make.width.equalTo(50)
  make.height.equalTo(50)
}
```

that your set w,h direct to frameSize will make AMBIGUOUS LAYOUT occur to your layout.

Comment: I have try'ed both cases. Nothing helps.